# Making a button clickable based on the value of a textbox

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I am trying to create a button that is unclickable at first. But when the user types in anything in a textfield, the button should be clickable. How do I do that? I know this will involve AJAX and I really don't know how to use AJAX. Any ideas how? Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I forgot to add that my textfield and button are inside separate fields in a CGridView. I'm sorry.

Comment: no ajax required just javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#some_text_box').on('input', function() {
    $("button").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="some_text_box" type="text"/>
<button id="button" type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>
```

with `jquery`

```
jQuery('#some_text_box').on('input', function() {
    $("#button").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: omg i forgot to add a very important part in my question. i'm sorry but thank you for answering. It'll come in handy soon.

Comment: you type in a value and make the button clickable. But if you remove the text, its still enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `keyup` function **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pygx3snv/1/)**

```
<input type='text' id='t1'/><button disabled id='button'>submit</button>
```

jquery:

```
$('#t1').on('keyup', function(){
    if($(this).val() != "") {
        $('#button').prop('disabled',false);
    }
    else {
        $('#button').prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```